# Hibernate - Don't map some fields from super class

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate 4.1 and Annotations for mapping from Java to DB.

I have super class whose attributes are mapped using `@MappedSuperClass`.

This class has many subclasses but some of the attributes are not valid for some subclasses, hence i don't want to map them to database for those subclasses.

Is there some way of achieving this?

Also, I am not sure if this is correct design or not where only the subset of properties of super class are applicable to subclass ? I am open to change design as well if some one could give me a valid reason.

That said, I am still interested in knowing whether original problem is solvable using JPA/Hibernate.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether or not there is a way to do what you want with Hibernate, but it sounds like the real problem is with your design/class structure. In short, the fields that don't apply to all of the subclasses probably shouldn't reside in the superclass.

You should either move the fields to the subclasses in which they apply, or create a new intermediate class with those fields and extend that instead. For example, consider this class structure:

```
class Animal {
  float weight;
  Color[] hairColors;
}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Fish extends Animal {}
```

`hairColors` doesn't apply to a `Fish`. We should move it to `Dog` or create a new intermediate class, e.g. `Mammal`:

```
class Animal {
  float weight;
}
class Mammal extends Animal {
  Color[] hairColors;
}
class Dog extends Mammal {}
class Fish extends Animal {}
```